# Nuxt.JS handling CORS request

Tags: cors, nuxt.js, preflight

i'm actually trying to connect the back-end of my web app to my front-end and i have to do a POST Request.

Back :  Angular1
-  Front: Nuxtjs / VueJS.

I have tried many method in front:

- like add the website in the manifest exceptions.
- use the google chrome plugin who desactivate CORS.
- put "application/form" or "plain/text" in the header.
- use asyncdata or fetch who do simulate a request as a backend.
- make a request with Ngrok.

this is my configuration on nginx

[image: config nginx]

and this the mistake

[image: config nginx]

i'm using axios and vue-ressources, i've tried both of them.

Kind regards

Comment: I don't understand: are you using nginx as a reverse proxy (https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy#using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy)?  If it was simply a Nuxt project connecting to an external REST API as it appears from the higher level, I would use Nuxt's implementation of axios and proxy and configure it as such (https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/1b46a95b0687a9a339f1fad4bcfc87b04416aeb4/examples/axios/nuxt.config.js)

Comment: You tried using the chrome plugin that deactivates CORS and you still had the issue? That's odd, that should have worked. Also I just checked the live website and I am not seeing the headers being added. https://i.imgur.com/6HSv5Tn.png